# Adding actions to Mobx observable array

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm just getting started with Mobx and I'm trying to add an action that removes an item from an observable array. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the store:

```
   class ToDoStore {
      @observable items = [];

      @action addItem = (item) => {
        this.items.push(item)
      }
      @action removeItem = (index) => {
        this.items.splice(index, 1)
      }

      @computed get itemCount(){
        return this.items.length;
      }

    }
```

Here's App.js:

```
    @inject('ToDoStore')
    @observer class App extends Component {

      handleRemove = (index) => {
        this.props.ToDoStore.removeItem(index);
      }


      render() {
        const {ToDoStore} = this.props;
        return (
          <div className="App">
             {ToDoStore.items.map((item, index )=> <li key={index}>{item}<button onClick={(index) => this.handleRemove(index)}>REMOVE</button></li>)}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Here's the error I'm getting when I click the 'remove' button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change your onClick handler to:

```
onClick={() => this.handleRemove(index)}
```

your were passing the event object as index!